# How to use Identity with PostgreSQL?

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

I have added `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` via nuget.

StartUp

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //Add PostgreSQL support
    services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()
        .AddDbContext<StoreDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseNpgsql(Configuration["Data:StoreDbContext:ConnectionString"]));
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddIdentity<PostgreApp.Models.User, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<StoreDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    // Add our PostgreSQL Repository
    services.AddTransient<IStoreRepository, StoreRepository>();
}
```

In StartUp' Configure I have added following:

```
app.UseIdentity();
```

This is my code:

```
 public class StoreDbContext: IdentityDbContext<User>
 {
    public StoreDbContext(DbContextOptions<StoreDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Store> Stores { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<JobPost> JobPosts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Candidate> Candidates { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CandidateCV> CandidateCVs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Criterion> Criteria { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AssessmentStage> AssessmentStages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AssessmentCriterion> AssessmentCriteria { get; set; }
    public DbSet<JobpostCv> JobpostCvs { get; set; }
}
```

Then I am getting this:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Column Id of type text has
>   ValueGenerated.OnAdd but no default value is defined    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.NpgsqlMigrationsSqlGenerator.ColumnDefinition(String
>   schema, String table, String name, Type clrType, String type,
>   Nullable`1 unicode, Nullable`1 maxLength, Boolean rowVersion, Boolean
>   nullable, Object default Value, String defaultValueSql, String
>   computedColumnSql, IAnnotatable annotatable, IModel model,
>   MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
>       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.ColumnDefinition(AddColumnOperation
>   operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder) 
>       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(CreateTableOperation
>   operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder, Boolean
>   terminate) 
>       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(CreateTableOperation
>   operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder) 
>       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(MigrationOperation
>   operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder) 
>       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(IReadOnlyList`1
>   operations, IModel model) 
>       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.GenerateUpSql(Migration
>   migration) 
>       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String
>   targetMigration) 
>       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String
>   targetMigration, String contextType) 
>       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.DatabaseUpdateCommand.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0()
>
> ```
> at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[]
> ```
>
> args) 
>       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)  Column Id of type text has ValueGenerated.OnAdd but no default
>   value is defined

How do I solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
services.AddIdentity<StoreDbContext, IdentityRole>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Instead of StoreDbContext you should be providing User(ApplicationUser) class.

What is the version of ASP.NET Core / EF Core that you are using?

Comment: Please don't ask questions in an answer. If you are not sure of the answer, add comments instead.

Comment: applied your suggestion. but still same error. i have also updated my code. please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the User objects implementation that it inherits the ApplicationUser properly. 
It seems like you have an entity which doesn't have the auto genaration policy properly implemented.

Can you check the applicationUser class in the migration file about the the way it's generating the user id property, as it is a GUID so it might need to handled.
You might have something like

```
 modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityRole", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<string>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

Where you are tryin to apply Autogenation on a string field.

and in your migration files you should have `Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGeneratedOnAdd", true);` associated with string values.

You can try implementitn the IdentityUser instead of string

```
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
    {
    }
```

Refer to the following link
https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/security/authentication/identity/sample/src